# JavaScript Pass Function Argument Out Along With Return Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I pass out the function argument of an ajax get in Java Script along with the return value?

In the example below, I want to bring through the value of the GetServer function argument `id` and make it accessible to the function `returnValue`

```
function getServerList(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/BackEndFunction/" + id,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: returnValue
        });
}

function returnValue(Data) {
    var _size = 0;
    var id= id // passed from getserverlist
    for (var i = 0; i< Data.length; i++) {
        _size += Data[i]._size;
    }
    data_dictionary[id] = _size;
}
```

Comment: Make it accessible how exactly? Does `returnValue` accept an argument?

Comment: Good point, missed that off, yes in short, I'll update the question.

Comment: you can try something like thid: if declare `returnValue` like `returnValue(param_id, responce)` so you can use `bind` like `success: returnValue.bind(this,id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous function to the rescue

```
function getServerList(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/BackEndFunction/" + id,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            returnValue(data, id);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Never used an anonymous function, fairly new js - function(data) - what is the data there? the data brought back from the Ajax call?

Comment: @JammAndTea: Yes. `$.ajax` calls the `success` callback when the response was received and pass it as first argument to the function.

Comment: F00kin' marvelous, thank you sir, good day! Will accept when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You could also proxy it

```
function getServerList(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/BackEndFunction/" + id,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: $.proxy(returnValue, this, id)
    });
}
```